# How do I change working directories with KDialog?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

Use-case: I am working in the terminal in /path/with/a/very/long/name and I want to change to some other directory that is deeply nested. But I don't know the path by memory. So I want to browse via a GUI to enable me to figure out where I need to navigate.

I came up with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "change working directory"
MYDIRECTORY=$(kdialog --getexistingdirectory ::label1);
if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
    cd "$MYDIRECTORY"
elif [ "$?" = 1 ]; then
    echo "action canceled";
else
    echo "ERROR";
fi;
exit 0
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. When the script exits, I remain in the original directory in the terminal. I have learned that this is because my original directory was restored when the subshell that executed the cd command exits.

So how can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: In researching this issue I also found [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki). It looks very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as a shell function (e.g. in your .bashrc) rather than a script file.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote it as a free standing script file and sourced it into my ~/.bashrc